# org.testng.TestNGException: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: testng

I am running the testng suite getting the error, but when i am running single testng test its running without error

org.testng.TestNGException: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

org.testng.TestNGException: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:325)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.initialize(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:136)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:97)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/

Answer (score 4):

use this xml header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
```

instead of the official one:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
```

Comment: Can you please tell me where to find this file ? I'm not able to find the file in src/test/resources or anywhere.